# Why we get error when we add any tag in between <img/> tag in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, custom-error-handling

**I have added span tag in between the img tag so its giving an error Please Explain Why it is giving an error. What the exactly problem is...**

```
<img src="any demo images here" alt="Nadeem">
                <span>adeem</span>
</img>
```

Comment: Because `img` is a self closing tag and you cannot give children to self closing elements and it applied not only to react but to whole html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the `img` tag can not have any child elements.

To get the result you are looking for you may want to wrap both the `img` and `span` in a wrapper `div` like this.

```
<div style={{position: "relative"}} />
    <img src="any demo images here" alt="Nadeem">   
    <span style={{position:"absolute", bottom: "0px", margin: "0px auth"}}>adeem</span> 
</div>
```

(I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but assuming so from your question)

Comment: When we write these code rather than react only in HTML its working Please help me out Why it is not working in React.If img is self closing tag then why it is working in pure HTML.<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600"><span>Nadeem</span></image>

Comment: @Nadeem Khan the reason it works in plain HTML is because the browser will sometimes ignore non compliant HTML and decide what to do with it, but the react compiler is throwing an error because it is just wrong, see my updated answer for a possible solution you may want to use. (PS even though it doesn't throw an error in plain HTML it is still prone to introduce bugs)

Comment: Great Man Thanks Shmili Breuer Sir

Comment: If it helped you please consider marking the answer as the accepted answer to help people who have the same question in the future.